# Insert symbol till the end of line

Tags: c#, ms-word, com-interop

I am using Interop.Word for my app. Now i'm trying to insert symbols (f.e. "_") till the end of line. The code is:

```
while (true)
{
    if (WordApp.Selection.Text == "\r")
        break;
    else
        WordApp.Selection.TypeText("_");          
}
```

But the problem is that `Range` is already at the paragraph mark ¶ and at once breaks the `while`. (I've also tried the `\r\n` condition but it also doesnt work) So, the picture of what i need is below:
[image]

Comment: Try convert.tochar(10).tostring() ?   You can always trace out the value and see what it is.

Comment: For exactly what you show, I'd place a right-aligned TabStop at the right margin with the underline as the tab-leader symbol. Then I'd insert a Tab character. Depending on what you're doing, it might even make sense to create a STLYE that has this predefined and apply the style as needed. Another possibility would be to use a two-column table and underline the right-hand cell.